# How to set permission for enable for Window phone 8.1 to work with input[type=file] page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, input-type-file

For Windows Phone 8.1 (with IE11), I can use **input[type=file]** to access local picture from the native browser, however, when I am using a webBrowser controller embedded inside the App, **input[type=file]** doesn't work (no response). I assume it will be some setting/permission for enabling embedded webBrowser controller to work like native browser. Does anyone know about that?

the URL I am testing on both browser is http://ryanjoy.com/2014/04/file-upload-in-ie11-on-windows-phone-8-1/

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you got any solution for it ? . I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

> WebView always uses Internet Explorer 10 in document mode. Additionally, WebView does not currently support HTML5, AppCache, IndexedDB, programmatic access to the Clipboard, or geo location, and supports only the Document Object Model (DOM) properties that are supported in Windows Store apps using JavaScript.

(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN1)

This is for Windows 8 but I guess nothing had changed with Windows 8.1 and IE11.

Comment: Thanks, however, I try to use webBrowser control, not WebView control, (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.105).aspx), I did the test on (http://ryanjoy.com/2014/04/file-upload-in-ie11-on-windows-phone-8-1/), it seems work file with native browser for input[type=file] control.

Comment: I just suspect the webBrowser control still use IE10 even it is for Windows 8.1, but why native web browser can use IE11?